# Google API Google Drive Node.js can´t upload file oAuth2

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api

Hey I tried for over 6h now and nothing working. I came this far..

I created a successfull connection to my api with this default code from the google api pages. I also enabled advanced features Google Drive at my console google page. I successfull created the token and it´s now stored at C:\Users\Administrator.credentials

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var google = require('googleapis');
var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/drive-nodejs-quickstart.json
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'];
var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
    process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'drive-nodejs-quickstart.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
    return;
  }
  // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the
  // Drive API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listFiles);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 *
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
  var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
  var auth = new googleAuth();
  var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
    } else {
      oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    }
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback to call with the authorized
 *     client.
 */
function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
  var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function(code) {
    rl.close();
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, token) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
        return;
      }
      oauth2Client.credentials = token;
      storeToken(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
 *
 * @param {Object} token The token to store to disk.
 */
function storeToken(token) {
  try {
    fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
  console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
}

/**
 * Lists the names and IDs of up to 10 files.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listFiles(auth) {
  var service = google.drive('v3');
  service.files.list({
    auth: auth,
    pageSize: 10,
    fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    var files = response.files;
    if (files.length == 0) {
      console.log('No files found.');
    } else {
      console.log('Files:');
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        console.log('%s (%s)', file.name, file.id);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

When I rerun this script I get

```
Files:
sample file.mp4 (123456789sampelcode)
projektname (123456789sampelcode)
Getting started (123456789sampelcode)
```

To the connection now worked with the token because I don´t need to do reenter something. I really don´t understand now how to upload a file. When i try to include my own upload function I can´t use it because I can´t combine it with the login process. I saw that

```
function listFiles(auth) {
}
```

Was default execuded after the login. So I thought I enter my code in this function it would work . So created this

```
function listFiles(auth) {
var drive = google.drive('v3');
var fileMetadata = {
  'name': 'photo.jpg'
};
var media = {
  mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
  body: fs.createReadStream('./photo.jpg')
};
drive.files.create({
   resource: fileMetadata,
   media: media,
   auth: auth,
   fields: 'id'
}, function(err, file) {
  if(err) {
    // Handle error
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('File Id: ', file.id);
  }
});

}
```

But nothing happen. My Terminal window is endless loading. No error no nothing.

Version 2 - This is my second version . also no log no nothing just endless loading. I turned of firewall so no way thats there a problem with the firewall or antivirus or somthing because in the default script I can see the files from my googledrive

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const google = require('googleapis');
const googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');
const drive = google.drive('v3');

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/drive-nodejs-quickstart.json
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];
var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
       process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'drive-nodejs-quickstart.json';


// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
     if (err) {
       console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
       return;
     }
     // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the
     // Drive API.
     //authorize(JSON.parse(content), listFiles);
     authorize(JSON.parse(content), real_upload_files);
});

/*
    * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
    * given callback function.
    *
    * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
    * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
    */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
     var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
     var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
     var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
     var auth = new googleAuth();
     var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);


     // Check if we have previously stored a token.
     fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
       if (err) {
         getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
         //console.log('5')
       } else {
         oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
         callback(oauth2Client);
         // console.log('4')
       }
     });
} // function authorize(credentials, callback) {





function real_upload_files(auth) {


var fileMetadata = {
     'name': 'photo.jpg'
};
var media = {
     mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
     body: fs.createReadStream('./photo.jpg')
};
drive.files.create({
      resource: fileMetadata,
      media: media,
      auth: auth,
      fields: 'id'
}, function(err, file) {
     if(err) {
       // Handle error
       console.log(err);
     } else {
       console.log('File Id: ', file.id);
     }
});


} // function real_upload_files(auth) {
```

Also If I would change auth: auth     to    auth: oauth2Client  and change it also in the function then will be same result endless loading screen.

Can somebody explain me pls how to upload files or do other stuff with the oAuth2. I find as node.js newbie that there are to less sample codes to find for for node.js .. Please help me guys I strugggle so hard with this.. please help :D With dropbox it takes 10 min but there I easy used a API Key ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your script is no wrong. In my environment, your script works fine. So I propose following 2 modifications.

#### Modification points :

1. What terminal do you use for this? It seems that from `C:\Users\Administrator.credentials` of your question, you use windows OS. If it's so, can you use `cmd.exe` for this? If you don't use windows. Please don't change the terminal.
2. How about the use of `readFile()` for reading the file? `readFile()` can read whole data in the file to the memory. So I thought that the error might be avoided. But if the file size is large, I recommend to use `createReadStream()`. I confirmed that `readFile()` and `createReadStream()` can use to upload file to Google Drive using `cmd.exe` as a terminal with windows OS.

**Modified script :**

```
function real_upload_files(auth) {
    fs.readFile('./photo.jpg', function(err, content){
        var fileMetadata = {
            'name': 'photo.jpg',
        };
        var media = {
            mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
            body: new Buffer(content, 'binary'),
        };
        drive.files.create({
            resource: fileMetadata,
            media: media,
            auth: auth,
            fields: 'id',
        }, function(err, file) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log('File Id: ', file.id);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I don't know whether these lead to the solution. I'm sorry.

Comment: yes now the endless loading stopped ! :D but I get Error: Insufficient Permission. I also install the google api php libary a few seconds ago and also get Error: Insufficient Permission. So yeha you are right my scripts are ok. I already on search what this problem is. It seems like a token problem. But I dont understand because I can view the files that are listet in my gdrive ? Also i change the scrop to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive - maybe redone the token process and create fresh one?

Comment: OMG finally it worked. I need to create a new token because the old was created with https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly instead of using https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive  Hope everybody can see this here if they have the same problem. They should make read warning that when you use the default script that you create a token that cant access anything hahaha omg :D however dude thank you so much without your awnser my endless screen wouldnt been away. love ya <3

Comment: @t33n I was relieved to hear that it worked fine. Thank you.